# How to return an express response when catching an error?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, error-handling

I catch and handle the error like so:

```
catch (err) {
    console.log(err);

    res.statusCode = 400;
    res.statusMessage = err;
}
```

The log works, however I don't receive a response in my browser and the call is "pending".

For the full code see: https://github.com/FrisoDenijs/WH40K-ArmyList/blob/3022f4a50b47eaecd2f5e68d6b67a16792217f1f/server/src/app/routes/detachments.route.js#L15

Comment: `return res.status(400).send(err)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`res.statusMessage` is not sending the response, use `res.send(err);` instead